# If I go in and remove car evaporator, does that mean I will no longer be getting any smell problems?

Tags: hvac, smell, evap

Despite using ac cleaners car smell keeps coming back.  Even if you use something like kool-it you can still expect it to return.

The only way to remove the problem is get to the source and clean\replace the evaporator.

1. Is it only the evaporator that will have the dirt or which other parts of the hvac system need replacing?
2. If I just remove the evaporator and do not put it back, does that mean I should no longer get any smell problems?
3. I think the Ac is used to clean the windscreen sometimes right?  So if the evaporator is moved, how will you accomplish that now?

Thanks

Comment: If it has a cabin filter, replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All parts of the ac circuit get dirty - which is why you need to clean them.

Removing the evaporator will not remove all the smell and will stop the ac working.

The ac can be used to demist the screen in many conditions - a task that used to happen before ac was so common by blowing air or using wipes.

Comment: new evaporators come with an anti-bacterial coating. It eventually wears off and mold grows on it. The cleaner/treatments work for a while, but they're not as effective and the factory coating. GM makes an "afterblow" device that runs the blower fan for 15-mins after shutdown to dry off the evap coil and prevent mold growth. YOu could try that.